# Intellij is not able to remember my git credentials

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I use Git Bash Desktop App with Intellij ide and our projects git repository hosted on TFS.
I need help in fixing or Disabling Auto git fetch in intellij idea.
As it keeps asking me for entering password every 15-20 minutes, however I can see credentials stored for git under windows credential manager vault.

[image: Intellij popup I keep getting]

[image: Windows Git credential manager]

Comment: Why not switching to ssh and get rid of passwords?

Comment: Hi @CodeWizard : ssh Sounds interesting,  but we are little new to git stuff, so could you please help me understand more how to get ssh keys? I mean who can help us getting it for team members and how we'll leverage it for windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)

```
# open git bash or terminal 
ssh-keygen
```

- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh directory` (or Users/.ssh under windows), open it and copy the content

  ```
  # get the ssh-key content
  cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```
- copy this key to your git lab account
- Get the ssh URL of your repository and update it in IntelliJ

Now you can use ssh instead of https

Comment: @CodeWzard: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I'll try this asap, And accept this as an Answer. And I hope ssh will handle our password changes also.

Comment: Here is the full doc:https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this thread, IntelliJ might have disabled the save passwords feature in native keychain. Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Passwords.
Make sure IDE is configured to save passwords either in Keychain or in KeePass.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008320219-GitHub-Token-not-saved-

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and enabling `Use credential helper` (at the bottom of the image) in `IntelliJ Settings > Version Control > Git` solved the issue for me

[image]